# Masquerade stopped working, throws validation error

Tags: 6

The Masquerade module has stopped working on my site. Drupal 6.28, (Drupal Commons 1.x) Masquerade 6.x-1.6.

When we enter a username in the Masquerade field the site throws the following error, does not let me masquerade, and redirects me to a profile page of a blocked user (http://www.hastac.org/users/bizworld) which  is most certainly not the user I was trying to masquerade as!

> Validation error, please try again. If this error persists, please contact the site administrator.

I tried disabling and renabling the module, removing and restoring the user permission to masquerade, and re-saving the module configuration page. Anyone know what's wrong or other solutions to try?

Comment: The last release of this module is 6.x.1.7  . You could update the module. IF the error persist, you should open a bug report in the offical page of the module: https://drupal.org/project/masquerade .

Comment: Whoops. Thank you for pointing that out! I'm updating it now and will report back.